# OOP - Proper design of an object with implementation-changing methods and semi-solid state

Tags: c#, oop

I'm looking for the proper design pattern for an object that needs different implementations for a ton of methods, the current implementation depending on one runtime-mutable variable.

Consider the following:

- A grid that consists of multiple hexes (tiles).
- Each tile has its own 'type' (Water / Fire et cetera)
- Each tile has a few fields (such as ItemsOnTop), some of which are shared for all types, while some are type-specific.
- Tiles can change their type, which changes the implementation of most methods and keeps some (but not all) fields intact.

The easiest and least OOPish solution would be to implement a single Tile class that'd keep the tile's kind in a field, possibly using an enumeration, such as

```cs
TileType type = TileType.WATER
```

and then, flood the methods' bodies with Switch statements checking for the TileType and altering the behaviour accordingly.

Another solution, perhaps cleaner, would be declaring a master Tile abstract class and derive all other tile types from it - such as WaterTile, Firetile and so on. The master class holds empty virtual methods for all behaviours of tiles, such as ExtinguishTile() - which is not overriden in WaterTile (cannot extinguish, so master class empty ExtinguishTile() is called and nothing happens) and overriden with relevant behaviour in the FireTile class.

The problem with this, at first glance better design, is that the type of a Tile can change runtime. We've got here an object of which we want to preserve the state (or at least, some of the fields), and also the need for different implementation of a ton of methods for each tiletype.

What would be the proper solution to it?

One 'workaround' would be to implement the second design. If a tile's object needs to be changed, destroy the old tile object, create the new tile object of desired type and shallow copy all fields that should carry over. It sounds a little iffy to me though, and perhaps somebody more experienced could add something.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like `Strategy` design pattern it is awesome, it's one of these patterns where you can say "Cool! I gonna be using this for everything!".

However I am uncertain whether it is really the best solution here.

If and when you need to change the *type* of an object - it is a strong indication that it's time to create a *new* object, otherwise it might break some of `OOP` and `SOLID` principles.

If I created a *Tiger* object and now I need a `Sheep` - I would create a new object for that rather than creating a generic object `Animal` with enum property `AnimalType`. The `TileType` property however should be there because it provides some  metadata about object without necessity of using Reflection's `GetType()` to check which type we are working with.

Mapping problem can be solved with simple mapping in Ctor,  custom mapper, `Automapper`, or factory. All of these approaches have their own cons and pros.

Let's have a look into how we could use simple mapping in ctor here:

```
public abstract class AbstractHex
{
    string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    ...
    string MyProperty10 { get; set; }
    ...
    TileType TileType { get; }

    protected Hex(AbstractHex hex = null)
    {
       if (hex != null)
       {
          this.MyProperty1 = hex.MyProperty1;
          // etc 
       }
    }

    ...
    Hex specific abstract or virtual methods
}

public sealed class WaterHex : AbstractHex
{
    // implements props here

    public WaterHex(AbstractHex copyFrom = null) : base(copyFrom)
    {
       TileType = TileTypes.Water;
    }

    ...
    override virtual methods with behavior specific for WaterHex
}

public sealed class FireHex : AbstractHex
{
    // implements props here

    public WaterHex(AbstractHex copyFrom = null) : base(copyFrom)
    {
       TileType = TileTypes.Fire;
    }

    ...
    override virtual methods with behavior specific for FireHex
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
var fireHex = new FireHex();

// this will copy data and change behavior 
var waterHex = new WaterHex(fireHex);
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Using this pattern, you can keep the instance of the `Tile` (the context) while changing its behavior at runtime by assigning a different strategy implementation (Fire, Water, ...).

Comment: Do you know of any C-Sharpish way to elevate the Strategy's methods to the master object's level (such as that you can call Object.Method instead of Object.Strategy.Method) without declaring a set of wrapper methods for each strategy?

Comment: @JohnSmith unfortunately not; the easy way would be to access the methods through the property of the strategy like `tile.Strategy.Method`. You could also declare an interface that both the strategy and the context implement. You'd still have to implement the methods, but you'd make sure that no method is forgotten. Only works if methods have same signature on context as on strategy which is not always the case.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are missing an abstraction that would simplify your design. I would think about whether the `Tile` should have all the things you describe or whether that can be split reasonably.

I'm thinking, what if we split your `Tile` concept to a `Position` and a `Tile`. The `Position` would be something that does not change at all, it is the abstraction of a particular place. This than *has* a `Tile`, *has* things on it, etc. Basically all the things that were previously "common" to tiles.

A `Tile` is just the behavior this position actually has, so it can easily transition to some other `Tile` without copying all the stuff that is actually associated with the `Position`.

I'm not familiar with your use-case, just an idea.